# How can I create pdf file from easy_pdf in django in new window?

Tags: django

In my view I return my content to pdf file

```
   return render_to_pdf_response(request, 'lease/pdf_lease_extension.html', {'data': data})
```

my html template is rendered into pdf file  based on easy pdf

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}
```

Right now when I generate pdf it always generates in same browser window.

How I can open pdf in different new windows each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow have to call your view.

So simply add `target="_blank"` to that link.

But before you force things to open in new windows/tabs, it might also be a good idea to [question why](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/) you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it will work.

```
response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                               template= 'easy_pdf/base.html',
                                               filename= filename,
                                               context= data,
                                               show_content_in_browser=False,
                                               cmd_options={ 'encoding': 'utf8',
                                                     'quiet': True
                                                   }
                                       )
pdf_content = response.rendered_content
```